# Cookies not working on my website, but work on localhost

Tags: php, cookies, host

So, my cookies aren't working on the live version of my website but will work on my localhost (test) version. Am I missing something here?

```
setcookie('cookieName', $cookie, strtotime( '+365 days' ) );
```

Here's what my code looks like. Do I need to declare cookie usage or something like that?

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['cookieName']) AND $_COOKIE['cookieName'] != ""){
   echo 'yes';
}else{
   echo 'no';
}
```

Here's an if statement that returns yes on localhost but no on live servers. They're in seperate files.

Update: the cookies work on Chrome and Opera, but not safari and firefox.

Comment: Always worth double checking the PHP version you are using is the same in both environments with `phpinfo();` on a test page.

Comment: And its safe for us to assume that you had a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: A common problem is that you have a whitespace (or enter) befor your opening <?php tag.

Comment: @Djave just checked it, live was on 5.5. Now live is on 5.6.8 and localhost is 5.6.7 but it still doesn't set the cookie.

Comment: @JacquesKoekemoer I just double checked the manual. It says no HTML before it, I only have PHP before it, would it be better to put the cookie in it's own file completely?

Comment: Not necessary you should be able to use code like that. I have a feeling that it doesn't like the time set on the cookie. If you use one of the cookies in the example on the manual does it then set the cookie? ie: `setcookie("TestCookie", "test");`. How do you know that the cookies aren't working on the live version? Have you tried using `print_r($_COOKIE);` to see what values are set? or even more possible, does your browser accept cookies from your live site? Is this a problem only in a browser or across multiple browsers?

Comment: @JacquesKoekemoer Just checked. Cookies set/work on Google chrome and Opera but not firefox or safari. I'm using print_r($_COOKIE) and it only returns PHP_SESSID on firefox and safari.

Comment: also, cookies are not immediately available when you require a page if cookies are set there. you may need to load twice and see if it's stored. check your headers also: curl -I http://yourdomain.com

Comment: @Trevor try to add a `sleep(2000)` to make it wait 2seconds before outputting the cookies.

Comment: @JacquesKoekemoer Thanks Jacques, but still no luck :/

Comment: You can find my contact details on www.jacqueskoekemoer.co.za, could you possibly send me a copy of your code (just the bit with the cookies) or upload it to a public website?

Answer (score 0):

try with this before setting any cookie:

```
ini_set("session.cookie_domain", ".yourdomain.com");
```

Comment: So if my website was "study.trevor.com" then ini_set("session.cookie_domain", "study.trevor.com"); would be right?

Comment: yes, but you may have more luck by lucking at headers try with curl, curl -I http://study.trevor.com and see what happens. remember that $_COOKIE is not immediately  available when you have set it, you'll see it on your next request to that domain

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$cookie_name = "cookieName";
$cookie_value = $cookie;
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 365), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
```

and then

```
if((isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) && ($_COOKIE[$cookie_name] != "")) {
 echo 'yes';
}
else{
 echo 'no';
}
```

The "/" means that the cookie is available in entire website (otherwise, select the directory you prefer).

Comment: Thanks Fatemeh, but no luck