# SetCookie() is not working in server - php

Tags: php, setcookie

**Note:** *This action works well in localhost. But it does not work on the live server!*

What I tried to do was to set the cookie:

```
<?php    
   $cookie_name = "user";
   $cookie_value = "John Doe";
   setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/", $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]);
?>
<!DOCTYPE>
...
```

And the warning I receive:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ...

Where am I wrong?

Comment: [Cookies not working on my website, but work on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30121553/2943403)

Comment: Next time you ask a question on Stack Overflow, include all of the pages that you found while researching; state how they did not resolve your problem and include any/all relevant debugging details that you discover while researching and attempting to the resolve your problem.  Do not allow people like me to close your questions with 5 duplicates.